# How to extract values from boost::python::list to C++

Tags: c++, python, linux, boost

I am creating .so files in linux so that i can import them in python scripts and start using them. I need to pass data from python to c++ layer so that i can use them. I am not able to extract the values despite referring to many posts. I have given the reference code below.
u8 => unsigned char

```
#include "cp2p_layer.h"

#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cp2p_hal)
{
    class_<SCSICommandsB>("SCSICommandsB")
        .def("Write10", &SCSICommandsB::Write10)
    ;
}
```

The following code is from cp2p_layer.cpp. I can get the length of the list but the data is always black

```
u16 SCSICommandsB::Write10 (u8 lun, u8  config, u32 LBA, u16 transferLen, u8 control, u8 groupNo,  boost::python::list pythonList)
{
    u16 listLen;
    u8*  pDataBuf = new u8[transferLen];

    listLen = boost::python::len(pythonList);
    if( listLen != transferLen)
    {
        cout<<"\nwarning: The write10 cdb has transfer length "<<transferLen<<"that doesnt match with data buffer size "<<listLen<<"\n";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < listLen; i++)
    {
        pDataBuf[i] = boost::python::extract<u8>( (pythonList)[i] );
        cout<<boost::python::extract<u8>( (pythonList)[i] )<<"-";
        //cout<<pDataBuf[i]<<".";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"info: inside write10 boost len:"<<listLen<<"\n";

    return oScsi.Write10 (lun, config, LBA, transferLen, control, groupNo,  pDataBuf);
}
```

When i execute the python script as

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cp2p_hal

scsiCmds = cp2p_hal.SCSICommandsB()
plist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print len(plist)
scsiCmds.Write10(0,0,0,10,0,0,plist)
```

The output comes as

```
10
--------        -
info: inside write10 boost len:10
```

Any help is much appreciated. I also have questions regarding how to read the data from the c++ layer once we have executed the read command. I will create a new post once i get this done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is only in your printing of the values.  A `u8` in C++ is an `unsigned char`, and `cout` will output the corresponding ASCII character.  Your characters (0-9) are unprintable, except for ASCII 9, which happens to be a tab.  Which explains the space before the final hyphen in your output.

How to fix it?  Cast to an int before outputting:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(boost::python::extract<u8>(pythonList[i])) << "-";
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation peter, it made sense. printing in hex made sense. also seems like we need to obtain the value from python as int and then we need to type cast it for our requirement.